# MaxRAMPercentage support in Java , is it only for container or we can use it outside container also

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed my java service on aws bean stalk and in procfile I want to specify  heap memory, I want to specify in such a way that even after changing the under laying hardware (RAM) my services should not get impacted and i figured out that instead of hardcoding the heap values (xmx , xms) I can specify it in percentage but later I got confused from this https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8196595

Is it only used inside the container or it can be used outside containers as well

Comment: Is it only used inside the container or it can be used outside containers as well? This is my question it has nothing to do with private information neither it is asked at work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MaxRAMPercentage is JVM parameter, so it is defined 'inside container' (if your terminology refer to a process that is running inside Elastic Beanstalk). Just as an additional note, to use it you can set in on AWS Console - Elastic Beanstalk - [instance] - Configuration - Modify Software - Environment properties --> add property name = "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS", value = "-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80", as an example.

The term "outside container" is confusing. However, referring to the bug you mentioned above, I guess you were confuse whether that JVM parameter is for java process inside Docker container or is it applicable to any/normal java process. Referring to this bug [8186315](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8186315), the MaxRAMPercentage is introduced. And then comes the bug [8196595](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8196595) introduced in JDK 10 to improve the execution and configurability of Java running in Docker containers.

So that means the XX:MaxRAMPercentage (and XX:InitialRAMPercentage and XX:MinRAMPercentage) are can be used inside docker container and can be used outside of docker container as well.